# Selecting option item by text instead of value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select id="State">
 <option value="Washington">WA></option>
</select>
```

This works

$('#State option[value="Washington"]')

but this doesn't

$('#State option[text="WA"]')

How can I do this??

Comment: is the extra `>` after WA a typo when pasting the code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#State option:contains("WA")')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z27Qx/1/)

Comment: It probably does, but then you have a typo in your question!

Comment: Oops sorry :) can you fix your answer and I will fix original question.